# My program stop when it saves files on the directory (inside the app directory) after creating the setup by inno setup Compiler?

Tags: c#, wpf, directory, inno-setup

On my project I have instructions that save Excel Files in a folder called "Ficheirs" inside the Project bin\debug directory (bin\debug\fichiers) using: Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\Fichiers" to set the path to that , it works well before creating the setup 
However after creating the setup using inno Setup Compiler , and eventually adding the folder "Ficheirs" while creating the setup , my program doesn't work 
How to fix that so that my program keeps saving my excel files on that folder ?

Comment: Add logs for you to know where the program blocks? I'd guess it's an authorization issue. Btw. instead of concatenating Paths manually, you'd better use Path.Combine().

Comment: Where do you install the program to?

Comment: What does "stop" and "does not work" mean? Be specific! What does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\Fichiers"`

This is a very unreliable function to set a path to a directory.
Without testing, the application can work in a different directory at the time you are asking for `GetCurrentDirectory()`.

e.g the working directory of the setup / App at the moment you run `GetCurrentDirectory()`

- **App**\
- **App\bin**\
- **App\bin\debug**\

---

`GetCurrentDirectory()+ "\Fichiers"` returns

- D:\Programs\App\Fichiers
- D:\Programs\App\bin\Fichiers
- D:\Programs\App\bin\debug\Fichiers

You should force at install all needed Dirs
Here is an example of a [Dirs] section:

```
[Dirs]
Name: "{app}\bin"
Name: "{app}\bin\debug"
Name: "{app}\bin\debug\Fichiers"
```

**inside C#**
Test before writing

```
 try 
     {
      // Set the current directory.
      string target = Application.StartupPath + "\\bin\\debug\\Fichiers";
      if (!Directory.Exists(target)) 
         {
           Directory.CreateDirectory(target);
         }
            // Change the current directory.
            Environment.CurrentDirectory = (target);
     ..............
```

**Setup iss**

```
[Code]
var
excelPath : String;

..............
excelPath := ExpandConstant('{app}\bin\debug\Fichiers');
```

Comment: Well that it has helped `[Dirs]`. Nevertheless, you should not use `GetCurrentDirectory()` to create a path. Use `Application.StartupPath` instead.